# Unity OnMouseUp() triggered when object is covered bu UI element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, raycasting

I have got some 2D elements in my scene with CircleCollider2D on them and a script with OnMouseUp(). At some stage a UI panel is rendered over the objects, and when I press a button that happens to be above the element with the OnMouseUp() it triggers both. I want to avoid disabling the circle collider every time the panel shows up and then enabling it after because of some other functionality. What can I do? Do I have to use raycasting?

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnMouseButton() does not answer objects in the *Ignore raycast* layer, so change the layer between those will solve your problem, another approach is to make an event when you open and close your menu and a bool field in your character like IsClickable, then you just toggle it as the answer to UI open/close event. Hope this helps

Comment: I think i might be to much of a noob, but as i understand, all 2d objects in the scene need to be on ignore raycast layer?

Comment: all 2d objects? just if you want that all of them ignore it, but if this is the case I strong suggest that you use another approach. I'm just saying that as you are using the OnMouseUp message to detect clicks, your objects in the ignore raycast layer should not be detected by it

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it might be the solution, ill try it after work

Comment: This was brilliant, took me a few minutes to understand how this can work together, but the answer is spot on, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the cursor is over UI. You can do this with the EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject() method, which returns a boolean. The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) for the method.